# Haskell with glade gtk+ requiredversion 3.20

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, glade

I installed glade from ubuntu software on 17.04, gtk and all dependency packages and I found out that the installed version of gtk+ (2.24) isn't compatible with glade Gtkbuilder format but gtk+ (3.20)+  is.
so I installed it manually from the .tar-gz file and it finished with no errors and when i run

```
dpkg -l libgtk* | grep -e '^i' | grep -e 'libgtk-*[0-9]'
```

it shows

```
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64             3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1 amd64        GTK+ 
graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-bin                 3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1 amd64        
programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-common              3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1 all          
common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-dev:amd64           3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1 amd64        
development files for the GTK+ library
ii  libgtk-3-doc                 3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1 all          
documentation for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2-perl                 2:1.24992-1build1  amd64        Perl 
interface to the 2.x series of the Gimp Toolkit library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64            2.24.31-2ubuntu1   amd64        GTK+ 
graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-bin                2.24.31-2ubuntu1   amd64        
programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-common             2.24.31-2ubuntu1   all          
common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-dev                2.24.31-2ubuntu1   amd64        
development files for the GTK+ library
```

which i guess means that I've 3.20+ installed (although I installed 3.20.10 idk why it shows 3.22.25) when i compile and run any .hs file using gtkBuilder glade format  ( ./test ) it says

```
test: test.glade: required gtk+ version 3.20, current version is 2.24
```

Is there any reason that glade isn't reading my install of 3.20.10 ? or any way to uninstall 2.24

Comment: I'd recommend you ask at superuser or askubuntu

Comment: Did you use the gtk3 Haskell package? The gtk Haskell package is only Gtk2 and will therefore not link or use the Gtk 3 libraries. Also there are 2 versions of Glade (one for Gtk 2, one for Gtk 3), so these all must match up.